# AndroidStudio manage dependencies

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

It may seem like a dumb question but when I add a maven dependecy in the gradle build file it gets resolved fine and everything works fine. However I dont get the dependency source code or javadocs even though those are available in maven repo and if i create an identical project with same deps in maven i get the source. I am using the latest version of AndroidStudio but I cant seem to find a way to make it work. This seems like a major feature and its definitely a deal braker for me (if i dont find a resolution I will just keep using maven and Intellij instead, since that works fine). Have you encountered a similar issue. I google a lot but all the fixes I saw were mostly patches or advised on downloading the source jars, etc. What's the point of downloading those manually if I were to use a dependency manager...? Any ideas will be highly appreciate, I am sure that someone here faced this same issue when they moved to gradle/Android Studio...

Comment: your are trying to place jar in gradle...

Comment: You'll get the same in plain IntelliJ/Gradle. From what I've heard, Android Studio doesn't support this yet (remember that it is a preview). I recommend to file a feature request or vote on an existing one.

Comment: They are working on it:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adt-dev/sources/adt-dev/BRZ5Y_LJuaw/RU78NqtB-dgJ

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59220